# Best permissions for file private key on webserver

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions

I have a PHP script on my web server that uses a private key so my directory structure looks like this

```
-- script.php
-- private-key
-- lib/
```

What permissions should I set my `private-key` file too so that it can be used by `script.php` but not by anyone else.  I've tried setting the permission as `664`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Setting your permissions as 664 means that anyone can read the file.  For a private key file, you should at least remove last 4 (660).  I would probably make the owner the user that is running script.php and then set the permissions to 400.

If your file permissions look something like this:

```
user@host:~$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x   3 apache  apache   4096 Jan  6 15:32 script.php
-rwxr-xr-x   2 apache  apache   4096 Dec 13 11:25 private-key
drwxr-xr-x  14 apache  apache   4096 Dec 13 15:03 lib/
```

Then something like this would be more secure:

```
chown apache:apache private-key
chmod 400 private-key
```

This will make it so the only user that can read the file is the apache user.

To make life a little easier for you, you might want to add a group and fiddle with the group permissions so that your user can edit the file as well.